# I downloaded this GDScript Plugin so i could learn the GD Script while feeling like I'm making progress! But it's code failed

Tags: error-handling, gdscript, godot4

```
extends Node

const ROOT_DIR := "user://user_settings"

var current_player := "Player"
var _loaded_profile: Profile
var uuid := UUID.v4()

func profile_exists(profile_name: String) -> bool:
    var file_path := _get_file_path(profile_name)
    return File.new().file_exists(file_path)


# Returns the profile designated by the provided name.
# If the profile does not exist, it will be created on the fly. If you do not
# want that to happen, check with `profile_exists` first.
#
# Loading a profile will set it as the current file name.
func get_profile(profile_name: String = current_player) -> Profile:
    if profile_name == current_player and _loaded_profile:
        return _loaded_profile
    
    current_player = profile_name
    var file_path := _get_file_path(profile_name)
    
    if not profile_exists(profile_name):
        var fs = DirAccess.new()
        var directory := file_path.get_base_dir()
        fs.make_dir_recursive(directory)
        
        var user_profile := Profile.new()
        user_profile.resource_path = file_path
        user_profile.player_name = profile_name
        
        _loaded_profile = user_profile
        Log.info({
            "id": UserProfiles.uuid,
            "profileName":profile_name
            }, "created profile")
        return user_profile
    
    Log.info({
        "id": UserProfiles.uuid,
        "profileName":profile_name
        }, "loaded profile")
    _loaded_profile = ResourceLoader.load(file_path) as Profile
    return _loaded_profile


func _get_file_path(file_name: String) -> String:
    return ROOT_DIR.plus_file(file_name) + ".tres"


func list_profiles() -> PackedStringArray:
    var profiles := PackedStringArray()
    
    var fs := DirAccess.new()
    var error = fs.open(ROOT_DIR)
    if error != OK:
        profiles.push_back(current_player)
        return profiles
    
    fs.list_dir_begin() # TODOConverter3To4 fill missing arguments https://github.com/godotengine/godot/pull/40547
    var file_name := fs.get_next()
    while not file_name.is_empty():
        if fs.current_is_dir() or file_name.get_extension() != "tres":
            file_name = fs.get_next()
            continue
        
        var profile = ResourceLoader.load(file_name) as Profile
        if profile:
            profiles.push_back(profile.player_name)
        
        file_name = fs.get_next()

    return profiles
```

Line 16:Identifier "File" not declared in the current scope.
Line 32:Native class "DirAccess" cannot be constructed as it is abstract.
Line 32:Name "new" is a Callable. You can call it with "new.call()" instead.
Line 56:Cannot find property "plus_file" on base "String".
Line 56:Function "plus_file()" not found in base String.
Line 62:Native class "DirAccess" cannot be constructed as it is abstract.
Line 62:Name "new" is a Callable. You can call it with "new.call()" instead.
Line 62:Cannot infer the type of "fs" variable because the value doesn't have a set type.
Line 69:Cannot infer the type of "file_name" variable because the value doesn't have a set type.

I Don't know GDScript, I had no idea what to try...

Answer (score 0):

About "DirAccess" cannot be constructed as it is abstract. In a nutshell, an abstract class is made to be inherited, it cannot be constructed. It isn't a feature in GDScript but it's in Godot's source code. A quick Look at the documentation revealed that what you want is probably *open* instead of *new*.

About "File" not declared in the current scope. I can't find Godot 4 documentation about File, only Godot 3 documentation. However in the DirAccess class there's *dir_exists_absolute (static)* and *dir_exists (not static)*.

I think the other errors are caused by those two. I hope I helped!